# cordova-plugin-fcm version conflict with gradle

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

After adding cordova-plugin-fcm plugin to my existing  cordova android project gradle build failed due to following error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

How should I resolve this error?

Comment: check the version of both of the dependency make sure that bot are same

Answer (score 0):

Remove android platform
on FCMPlugin.gradle (plugin folder) edit like this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

Then on plugin.xml file

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4" />
```